# $push value to array with mongoose only if key is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to push a subdocument but only if a certain key is present in the update request. At the moment if the `status_value` key is not present in req, an empty subdocument is added with just an `_id` field.

My update function is as follows

```
Audit.findByIdAndUpdate(id, 
                       {$set:req, $push: { status: {status_value: req.status_value }} },  
                       { new: true, runValidators: true })
                       .lean().exec( function (err, audit) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      callback(err, null)
    }
    else if (!audit) {
      console.log("update_fucntion user not found")
      callback(null, null)
    }
    else {
      console.log('finished update\n\n')
      console.log(audit)
      callback(null, audit)

    }
  });
```

The obvious option is to put an `if` clause but this would therefore mean putting two `Audit.findByIdAndUpdate` functions. Is there a cleaner/ alternative way of accomplishing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by **undefine**

```
var where = '...query'
if (req.key != undefined) {          //Key is exist in request
    where['$push'] = 'Do your stuff'
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, could you just clarify it a bit

Comment: Ya sure, I have set one variable `where` which has query data. Then I have checked that `key` is available in request ? If key is present in request that mean it is not `undefined`. It has some value. So when you got key in `request` then I have add `$push` in `where` variable dynamically. This is what I'm using in my code. I hope it may helps you... :)